# using queryset in forms django

Tags: django

**hi My friends, I want to show only the professors of the same branch in the form, but it is not possible**

forms.py

```
class ClassesForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Classes
        fields = [
        'sath',
        'code',
        'name',
        'gender',
        'teacher',
        'meeting',
        'holding',
        'teadadjalasat',
        'sen',
        'datestart',
        'miantermstart',
        'dateend',
        'description',
        'room',
    ]

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
            super(ClassesForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
            self.fields['teacher'].queryset = Profile.objects.filter(semat__icontains="teacher", status=1,branch=request.user.branch)
```

> NameError at /operation/classes/create/
>
> name 'request' is not defined

vlews.py

```
class classesCreate(ClassesInline, CreateView):

def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
    ctx = super(classesCreate, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
    ctx['named_formsets'] = self.get_named_formsets()
    return ctx

def get_named_formsets(self):
    if self.request.method == "GET":
        return {
            'reservs': ReservationFormSet(prefix='reservs'),
        }
    else:
        return {
            'reservs': ReservationFormSet(self.request.POST or None, self.request.FILES or None, prefix='reservs'),
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

> add in view

```
def get_form_kwargs(self):
    kwargs = super().get_form_kwargs()
    kwargs['request'] = self.request
    return kwargs
```

> add in forms.py

```
def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    request = kwargs.pop('request')
    super(ClassesForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
    self.fields['teacher'].queryset = Profile.objects.filter(semat__icontains="teacher", status=1, branch=request.user.branch)
    self.fields['code'].value = Classes.objects.all().filter(branch=request.user.branch).count()
```